# Running PHP after request

Tags: php

I would like to be able to start a second script (either PHP or Python) when a page is loaded and have it continue to run after the user cancels/navigates away is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send Connection:Close headers, which finishes the page for your user, but enables you to execute things "after page loads".

There is a simple way to ignore user abort (see [php manual](http://de3.php.net/ignore_user_abort) too):

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Comment: well,also call  session_write_close() :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [process forking with pcntl](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/php/process-forking/).
It only works under Unix operating systems, however.

You can also do something like this:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php ./child_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

You can read more about the above example [here](http://www.welldonesoft.com/technology/articles/php/forking/).

Answer (score 2):

for keeping the current script:

- ignore_user_abort(true);
- set_time_limit(0);

for running another script:

- see $sock=fsockopen('http://localhost/path_to_script',80,$errorStr,3600) + stream_set_timeout($sock,3600);
- see exec('php path_to_script'); - this will cause your script to run from the CLI, so you'd have to install php-cli on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you can't use the others is to include an img tag at the bottom of your output that requests a php page that does whatever it is you are wanting to do.

It will still show the loading animation though, so I think Karsten's suggestion is probably better (I'll try that next time I need to do this type of thing I think).