# Run PHP script in background on submit button click without page reload

Tags: php

I need to run a php script (site crawler) on submit button click without a page reload. After the background script run, A confirmation / alert popup should appear that the site crawler is ended. Any Ideas Please?

Comment: Try Ajax, if you don't want to reload the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a php script in the background in another php script (like an update button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257398/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-in-another-php-script-like-an-update)

Comment: A lot of information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea goes like this:

- you send and [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) call to server and execute script
- script checks if there is already a background process

  - if there is one, return the status code
  - if on background script running: script [forks itself](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) , returns an "OK" response and start to do the work
- with a different XHR call you repeatedly check if script has finished
- when the server-side script has finished running, you gather the results and diplay in the page

To simplify the interaction with server, you might want to use some of the [XHR libraries](http://microjs.com/#ajax). I would avoid suggest to avoid slapping on jquery unless you are actually already using it for something else.

As for "how to know when background script has finished" : i think the best way would be for that script to create a file, which contains

- when running: -1
- when finished: 0
- when error: positive number

Answer (score 0):

Jquery + AJAX could make your job easier. Read this tutorial on how to achieve the result:

[AJAX+ jQuery Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp)